# Sonarqube error: Change this code to not reflect user-controlled data

Tags: html, sonarqube, xss

SonarQube is flagging the following code to not reflect user=controlled data. I understand the fix I have to implement (validate the url), but I don't know how to do it. In the code below, it doesn't like the use of previous_page in the href. Any idea how I can validate previous_page?

```
{% if previous_page %}
     {% if index not in previous_page %}
           Click <a href="{{ previous_page|safe }}">here</a> to go back to where you were.
     {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```